# General SQL Parser , get subquery out of SQL

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, select

I am using [General SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) to parse a SQL Select query, what is unclear is the document of GSP does not say how to extract subquerys， For Example if i have the following SQL:

```
 select * from table1 join (subquery) as T2 on table1.a=T2.a
```

where subquery is another select query all over again. how do i get subquery string so i can apply GSP rule over it ？

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here is demo code that they provide... ([taken from here)](http://www.dpriver.com/gsp/demos/csharp/iterateStatement/iterateStatement.cs):

"
This demo illustrate how to find out all kinds of SQL statements in a script quickly. Find out all SQL statements inside a PLSQL block/package/procedure/function; Find out nested subquery in a select/delete/update statement; Find out querys in a union select statement; Find out sub-queries in where clause, select list and etc.
"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

using gudusoft.gsqlparser;
using gudusoft.gsqlparser.Units;

namespace findsubquerys
{
    class prg
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int c = Environment.TickCount;

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} scriptfile", "syntaxcheck");
                return;
            }

            TGSqlParser sqlparser = new TGSqlParser(TDbVendor.DbVMssql);
            sqlparser.Sqlfilename = args[0];
            int iRet = sqlparser.Parse();

            if (iRet == 0)
            {
                foreach (TCustomSqlStatement stmt in sqlparser.SqlStatements)
                {
                    printStmt(stmt);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax error found in input sql:");
                Console.WriteLine(sqlparser.ErrorMessages);

            }
        }

        static void printStmt(TCustomSqlStatement pstmt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pstmt.AsText+"\n");

            for (int j = 0; j < pstmt.ChildNodes.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (pstmt.ChildNodes[j] is TCustomSqlStatement)
                {
                    printStmt((TCustomSqlStatement)(pstmt.ChildNodes[j]));
                }
            }

        }

    } //class
}
```

Comment: Thx for the example, I manage to run your code, printStmt print each statement in a new line. here is the output: